# How can I visualize per-character differences in Github diff view?

Tags: github

Currently it only shows the lines that are different. Any way to make it visualize per-character difference *inside* these lines?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to also "vertically" visualise differences? What exactly are you trying to do/achieve? (Or why aren't the per-line differences sufficient?)

Comment: Are you asking about the GitHub website, the GitHub Windows program, the GitHub Mac program, or the GitHub Eclipse plugin?

Comment: @Chris, I'm asking about the primary Github, i.e. Github website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GitHub does that out of the box, see e.g. [this changeset](https://github.com/kriegaex/Galileo-Openbook-Cleaner/commit/2bc52c88d269ae197c15ebe8ea45bc39f14398af).

Here is a screenshot, just in case your monitor does not show the colours right:

[image: Diff view with in-line changes highlighting]

Comment: Hmmm. Indeed, it does - at least in some cases. However, I have a number of commits, where it doesn't show per-character difference. :-/ I wonder why this can happen.

Comment: Give me a link to an example, and I can take a look. Maybe I have an idea.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. It's a private repo.

Comment: PS unfortunately, this doesn't work in the "staged for commit" diff.

Comment: Have you changed the topic after 7 years? The question was about the GitHub website. Why would that website have a "staged for commit" diff view? Are you talking about a local development tool now?

Comment: Ah, forgot what it was about initially. Probably it's better to ask in a separate question.